# Enable XPath2 queries in System.Xml.XPath (XPathException: invalid token)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

Microsofts System.Xml.XPath nuget-package, available for .NET 4.6, claims to support XPath 1.0 and 2.0. De [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath(v=vs.110).aspx) says descibes the namespace:

*The System.Xml.XPath namespace contains the classes that define a cursor model for navigating and editing XML information items as instances of the XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Data Model.*

After upgrading Visual Studio, upgrading and all my projects to framework version 4.6 I still can't get the simplest XPath-2.0 for-expression to work. According to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-for-expressions), they should work.

I can't imagine Microsoft claiming to support something it actually doesn't, so obviously I'm doing something wrong. **How do I correctly use an XPath2 query?**

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestXPath2()
{
    // The System.Xml.XPath namespace contains the classes that define a cursor model for navigating and editing XML information items as instances of the 
    // XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Data Model.

    var expression = "for $x in /Root/Foo/Bar return $x";
    var compiledExpression = System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression.Compile(expression); 
    // throws XPathException: "for ... has an invalid token"
}
```

P.S.
What I actually want, is to get something like this to work:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestLibraryForCustomer1()
    {
        string xmlFromMessage = @"<Library>
            <Writer ID=""writer1""><Name>Shakespeare</Name></Writer>
            <Writer ID=""writer2""><Name>Tolkien</Name></Writer>
            <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer1"" /><Title>King Lear</Title></Book>
            <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer2"" /><Title>The Hobbit</Title></Book>
            <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer2"" /><Title>Lord of the Rings</Title></Book>
             </Library>"; 

        var titleXPathFromConfigurationFile = "./Title"; 
        var writerXPathFromConfigurationFile = "for $curr in . return /Library/Writer[@ID=$curr/WriterRef/@REFID]/Name";

        var library = ExtractBooks(xmlFromMessage, titleXPathFromConfigurationFile, writerXPathFromConfigurationFile).ToDictionary(b => b.Key, b => b.Value);

        Assert.AreEqual("Shakespeare", library["King Lear"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("Tolkien", library["The Hobbit"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("Tolkien", library["Lord of the Rings"]);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestLibraryForCustomer2()
    {
        string xmlFromMessage = @"<Library>
                <Writer ID=""writer1"">
                    <Name>Shakespeare</Name>
                    <Book><Title>Sonnet 18</Title></Book>
                </Writer>
                <Writer ID=""writer2"">
                    <Name>Tolkien</Name>
                    <Book><Title>The Hobbit</Title></Book>
                    <Book><Title>Lord of the Rings</Title></Book>
                </Writer>
            </Library>";

        var titleXPathFromConfigurationFile = "./Title";
        var writerXPathFromConfigurationFile = "../Name";

        var library = ExtractBooks(xmlFromMessage, titleXPathFromConfigurationFile, writerXPathFromConfigurationFile).ToDictionary(b => b.Key, b => b.Value);

        Assert.AreEqual("Shakespeare", library["Sonnet 18"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("Tolkien", library["The Hobbit"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("Tolkien", library["Lord of the Rings"]);
    }


    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> ExtractBooks(string xml, string titleXPath,  string writerXPath)
    {
        var library = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        foreach(var book in library.Descendants().Where(d => d.Name == "Book"))
        {
            var title = book.XPathSelectElement(titleXPath).Value;
            var writer = book.XPathSelectElement(writerXPath).Value;
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(title, writer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "the XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Data Model" is a reference to the relevant standard - it is not meant to imply that xpath 2 navigation is supported. I can't immediately find where in the docs it explains that only xpath 1.0 is supported; if I can I will put it in an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomalek pointed out correctly:

- XPath 2.0 is not supported in .NET (in System.Xml.XPath), period
- The data model and the query language are separate things.

So I solved it by using a third party XPath 2 library, The [XPath2 nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPath2/). This allows for expressions like

```
for $c in . return ../Writer[@ID=$c/WriterRef/@REFID]/Name
```

Note that I needed to use a relative path from book to writer. This does **not** work:

```
# does not work due to the absolute path
for $c in . return /Library/Writer[@ID=$c/WriterRef/@REFID]/Name
```

For future reference: this code works after installing the nuget pacage:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Wmhelp.XPath2;

namespace My.Library
{
    [TestClass]
    public class WmhelpTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void LibraryTest()
        {
            string xmlFromMessage = @"<Library>
                <Writer ID=""writer1""><Name>Shakespeare</Name></Writer>
                <Writer ID=""writer2""><Name>Tolkien</Name></Writer>
                <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer1"" /><Title>King Lear</Title></Book>
                <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer2"" /><Title>The Hobbit</Title></Book>
                <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer2"" /><Title>Lord of the Rings</Title></Book>
            </Library>";

            var titleXPathFromConfigurationFile = "./Title";
            var writerXPathFromConfigurationFile = "for $curr in . return ../Writer[@ID=$curr/WriterRef/@REFID]/Name";

            var library = ExtractBooks(xmlFromMessage, titleXPathFromConfigurationFile, writerXPathFromConfigurationFile).ToDictionary(b => b.Key, b => b.Value);

            Assert.AreEqual("Shakespeare", library["King Lear"]);
            Assert.AreEqual("Tolkien", library["The Hobbit"]);
            Assert.AreEqual("Tolkien", library["Lord of the Rings"]);
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void TestLibraryForCustomer2()
        {
            string xmlFromMessage = @"<Library>
                <Writer ID=""writer1"">
                    <Name>Shakespeare</Name>
                    <Book><Title>Sonnet 18</Title></Book>
                </Writer>
                <Writer ID=""writer2"">
                    <Name>Tolkien</Name>
                    <Book><Title>The Hobbit</Title></Book>
                    <Book><Title>Lord of the Rings</Title></Book>
                </Writer>
            </Library>";

            var titleXPathFromConfigurationFile = "./Title";
            var writerXPathFromConfigurationFile = "../Name";

            var library = ExtractBooks(xmlFromMessage, titleXPathFromConfigurationFile, writerXPathFromConfigurationFile).ToDictionary(b => b.Key, b => b.Value);

            Assert.AreEqual("Shakespeare", library["Sonnet 18"]);
            Assert.AreEqual("Tolkien", library["The Hobbit"]);
            Assert.AreEqual("Tolkien", library["Lord of the Rings"]);
        }


        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ExtractBooks(string xml, string titleXPath, string writerXPath)
        {
            var library = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            foreach (var book in library.Descendants().Where(d => d.Name == "Book"))
            {
                var title = book.XPath2SelectElement(titleXPath).Value;
                var writer = book.XPath2SelectElement(writerXPath).Value;
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(title, writer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an extra external dependency and more code than using LINQ. Why not use LINQ?

Comment: @Tomalek To be able to configure the XML structure. Every customer will send differently structured files. The actual mapping from XML entities to my application classes is configured per customer.

Comment: That's fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the XPath 2.0 query language really is supported.

But for something as simple as your requirement, an XPath 1.0 one-liner is sufficient.

```
string xml = @"<Root>
    <Foo ID=""foo1"">One</Foo>
    <Foo ID=""foo2"">Two</Foo>
    <Bar><FooRef REFID=""foo2"" /></Bar>
    </Root>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var matchingFoo = doc.XPathSelectElement("/Root/Foo[@ID = //Bar/FooRef/@REFID]");

Assert.AreEqual("Two", matchingFoo.value);
```

For queries that exceed the capabilities of XPath 1.0, try using LINQ.

In your extended example, what you want to do us link books to their authors. This is easily done in a LINQ join, like this:

```
var xmlFromMessage = @"<Library>
    <Writer ID=""writer1""><Name>Shakespeare</Name></Writer>
    <Writer ID=""writer2""><Name>Tolkien</Name></Writer>
    <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer1"" /><Title>King Lear</Title></Book>
    <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer2"" /><Title>The Hobbit</Title></Book>
    <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer2"" /><Title>Lord of the Rings</Title></Book>
     </Library>"; 

var libraryDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlFromMessage);

var library = from title in libraryDoc.Descendants("Title")
    join writer in libraryDoc.Descendants("Writer")
    on title.Parent.Element("WriterRef").Attribute("REFID").Value equals writer.Attribute("ID").Value
    select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(title.Value, writer.Value);
```

Now `library` is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` with title/writer pairings.

Comment: Maybe you should have made your example clearer, then? Instead of describing what implementation you want to use to achieve an unexplained goal, you could have described what goal you want to achieve and leave the implementation open for debate (aka the XY-problem). XPath 2.0 is not supported in .NET, period. Use LINQ, or use an alternative approach with XPath 1.0. `/Root/Foo[@ID = //Bar/FooRef/@REFID]` selects *all* `<Foo>` nodes that have a matching `@REFID`. This could be filtered down to the particular one you want in a second step.

Comment: +1 for this comment. "XPath 2.0 is not supported in .Net." That's an answer I work with. I'll try some third party libraries. (Still: The NuGet package description suggets it does: Provides the classes that define a cursor model for navigating and editing Extensible Markup Language (XML) information items as instances of the XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Data Model.

Comment: The data model and the query language are separate things. I can't see any indication in your code that the built-in tools can't be used to do what you want, though. And I might even be able to suggest a way to do it if I only knew what it was you wanted to do in the first place.

Comment: I changed the second example. I'm using XPath to configure how to interpret an XML file. I got the second example to work using https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPath2/. I'll post the code here for future reference.

Comment: "XPath 2.0 is not supported in .Net." Wrong. What you mean is, Microsoft's XPath products do not support XPath 2.0. In the wider ecosystem, if you're prepared to look beyond Microsoft, there are certainly XPath 2.0 (and 3.0/3.1) implementations available that run in .NET.

Comment: @MichaelKay Of course, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @realbart Take a look at the answer update, a LINQ solution is very straight-forward.

Comment: @MichaelKay I think that's what Tomalak meant. And in the end, that's also the solution I picked. I just got confused because the System.XML.XPath explicitly names XPath 2.0. That lead me to falsely assume that this package implemented everything described in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/.