# why I get an invalid token while using Xpath if-then-else Expression with c# XPathNavigator Evaluate?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

I get an invalid token exception while trying to evaluate below expression via XpathNavigor:

```
var expression = if(//DovizCins = 'YTL') then '1' else '2';

var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
XPathExpression xp = XPathExpression.Compile(expression);
var value = nav.Evaluate(xp);

return value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

Exception is:

System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: ''if(//DovizCins = 'YTL') then '1' else '2'' has an invalid token.'

Comment: I think the expression is missing an = and it should be DovinzCins == ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's XML technology is way out of date. This is XPath 2.0 syntax, introduced in 2007, and Microsoft has yet to catch up: they're still shipping XPath 1.0.

Comment: But here it says there is classes and methods for processing xpath 2.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: It talks about supporting the XPath 2.0 *data model* but not the XPath 2.0 language. (They're either being disingenuous, or they got half way to doing 2.0 and then stopped). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805830/enable-xpath2-queries-in-system-xml-xpath-xpathexception-invalid-token

Answer (score 1):

I completely concur with Michael Kay.

The official MS documentation is mistaken: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath?view=netframework-4.7.1

**Excerpt**

*"...The System.Xml.XPath namespace contains the classes that define a cursor model for navigating and editing XML information items as instances of the XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Data Model..."*

**XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0** are partially supported by MS SQL Server.
The .Net framework doesn't support any XQuery, and its XPath is 1.0